# What is the minimum temperature to keep the hot water heater at?

Tags: plumbing, hot-water, temperature

Our hot water heater produces hot water, but not super hot, is there a minimum temperature I need to keep it at?

I don’t like it when the hot water is scalding, but I want to be safe.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What temperature should I set my water heater to?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/29929/2196)