# Need guidance and advice for a mixing valve

Tags: plumbing, shower

I'm debating installing a mixing valve on my shower to hopefully eliminate the routine scalding associated with taking a shower. I've read a bit online but I have questions.

- I haven't seen a P&ID of an installation. With a two valve system, should the mixing valve be installed upstream of the hot water valve and cold water be plumbed in like normal?
- I have seen advice suggesting check valves. Do I need them on both sides or just the cold side?
- Any recommended brands or styles?
- Any other tips?

Comment: Where are you? What kind of water heater do you have: central tank, central tankless, or point of use? Sounds like you are thinking of combining components to get a system that performs well, b ut it really doesn't work that way nowadays. You install a single integrated system which meets the plumbing code. Do you want to redo the tile on the control wall? Is this a shower or a tub/shower with diverter?

Comment: Central tank. And it's a tub/shower with a total of four valves. Two for the shower and two for the bath. What would you suggest?  I have access to the pluming from an access panel behind the faucet.

Comment: So the tub and the shower have totally separate valves; no diverter, right? Interesting, I've never seen that or I don't remember.  Is this in the US? You *could* leave the tub valves as is and only change the shower valves. What is the stem-to-stem spacing between the valve handles for the shower? I think the normal in the US would be 8", and 6" (150 mm) in Europe.  Is this an old bathroom so the construction is plaster over metal lathe w or w/o ceramic tile over that? Be a shame to demo that; maybe there is a way to save the tile.

Comment: The thermostatic bar mixing valve is common in Europe but available on a limited basis in the US. The ones I have seen require approximately 6" spacing between the supply pipes to the shower mixing valve.

Comment: I don't have a tape measure handy but I believe it's at least 8. Also you are correct. White tile on rock lathe. The home is moderately old. 1944. I was looking at the watts brand valves.

Comment: Personally I like to make existing fixtures work rather than replacing them. I hope you can get a thermostatic valve that will make your existing valves work. Do you know the brand and model? Presumably they have rubber or plastic 'washer' seals and replaceable brass seats. Are there cut-off valves in the wall or 'stop valves' as part of the valve  body? The older valves with plastic washer seals do require replacement more often than newer types of valves. From what I have seen shower and tub valves do not normally have cut-offs like lavatories, sinks, and toilets.

Comment: This is the valve I have been reading about. [link](http://www.watts.com/pages/learnAbout/temperingValves.asp?catId=) It would appear that it is on the installer to install check valves.

Comment: The Watts valve looks like a good one. Why do you keep talking about "check valves"? Do you mean cut-off or stop valves for the shower and/or tub? A check valve is a valve that allows flow in one direction, but stops it from flowing in the other direction. AFIK check valves have no use in household water plumbing. A check valve is *sometimes* used in the sewer line in the yard if there is a threat that sewage from the city sewer could back up into the house's sewer.

Comment: Watts recommends a check valve to prevent thermal siphoning.

Comment: OK, but the exact check valve might be important for proper function. Do Watts specify the exact one? Would this be a single check valve to prevent hot water flowing into the cold line at  the T or Y where the cold feed goes to the Watts thermostatic valve? Or are two check valves needed? This is getting complicated. Don't count on a plumber having the needed check valve on his truck. Find out from Watts what they recommend and get it yourself.

Comment: That's actually what I was asking about. Watts only calls for one to prevent hot water from transfering to the cold pipes due to the temperature gradient (thermosiphoning).  I would assume you would place it on the cold side.  I just wanted to confirm this.  As for the parts, I would be doing the work myself.  I wouldn't expect plumbers to carry all the parts I need.

Comment: Ideally you would want a check valve installed on both inlet connections of the thermostatic mixing valve. Often the valve comes with simple ones builtin. The valve creates a cross connection of the two systems. Depending on the arraignment of piping and pressure differences between the two systems, you can get cross transfer. This becomes more critical if you have a hot water recirculation system.

Comment: Yes the valve I was looking at does have simple check valves but recommends at least one. I was thinking I may need two. However now I'm skeptical if the only thing this is going to do is limit the upper end of the temperature.

Comment: It is good to think about what you would get for this trouble and expense. If you have young children who are showering by themselves or being showered by another person who might not be that attentive, or you have a handicapped or elderly person who might not be aware of scalding, then the anti-scald valves could prevent serious injury.  What would be the time scale for this Watts valve to respond to a lowering of the pressure in the cold water line? What are the exact conditions where you are now sometimes getting too much hot water during showering?

Answer (score 1):

If your existing shower is a two handle type (independently controlled hot and cold) the simplest solution would be to install a [temperature actuated flow reducer](http://www.bostonstandardplumbing.com/add-a-temperature-activated-flow-reducer-to-your-older-shower/). This devise can be added inline between the shower head and the shower arm. It will reduce the flow out of the shower head as the temperature gets too hot. This will give you time to adjust the temperature before getting scalded.

The best solution is to replace the existing shower valve with a modern [pressure balanced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure-balanced_valve) one. This type of valve will adjust the flow of the hot if there is a drop in pressure on the cold side due to a toilet being flushed. This would require you to open up the wall in order to replace the valve (easy if the back side of the shower wall is accessible).

**Update:** Some manufactures sell a cover plate for converting two (or three) handle shower valves to pressure balanced ones. The cover plate conceals the leftover holes in the tile from the old valve. Here's a clip from [Ask This Old House](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6Pk7RQA9ag) on installing one.

If you’re not able to replace the valve, but the water lines are accessible (in an attic or basement), you could install a point-of-use [thermoplastic mixing valve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermostatic_mixing_valve) on the hot line that feeds the shower valve.

You can also adjust the [temperature of your hot water tank](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29929/what-temperature-should-i-set-my-water-heater-to#29930), however you don't want to set it too low as you would increase the risk of pathogens.

Lastly, adding check valves will not help if the issue is pressure balance.

Comment: Thanks,  I wanted to avoid replacing the tile. I would prefer to keep my water heater >=140F to prevent pathogens.  I do have access to the piping.  I was going in the direction of adding a thermoplastic mixing valve.  The questions I asked above were in regard to that.

Comment: So would this be a thermostatic valve in the hot water line to the shower valve. This would involve mixing in cold water with very hot water to go to the hot valve of the shower valve pair.  This would reduce the temperature of the hot water to the shower mixing valve so that temperature swings would be greatly reduced. The temp of the hot water might be limited to say 110 F and this would be mixed with cold water at say 60 F to get to a comfortable temperature for a shower. Is the piping in the wall copper tubing?

Comment: Yes. All the pipes are soldered copper.

Comment: So are you thinking of having the mixing valve accessible from the shower side or by opening an access panel on the back side? Do you plan to adjust the mixing valve only monthly or seasonally as the temperature of the cold water changes?  Is this a thermostatic mixing valve? http://www.supplyhouse.com/Honeywell-Sparco-AM100-US-1LF-1-2-Lead-Free-Union-Sweat-Mixing-Valves-70-145F?gclid=CjwKEAiAirXFBRCQyvL279Tnx1ESJAB-G-Qv2DGQ1udOEqPQuT0d5tLVnHO-_-1kyKXPPM9XcBi77hoC3HHw_wcB

Comment: Regarding the location of the thermostatic mixing valve: can be installed anywhere on the hot line that serves the shower valve. The cold would stay connected as is with the exception that a tee would need to be installed in order to connect cold to the thermostatic mixing valve. However, if you are experiencing scalding due to pressure balance issues, installing a thermostatic mixing valve will prevent the scalding but will not stop the nuisance of fluctuating temperatures.

Comment: @pdd Really? I thought that was the whole point of those valves, to act as a buffer to rapid pressure changes by adjusting temperature. I guess if thats the case, its probably not worth the effort.

Comment: The valve will adjust the hot water going into the shower to the lower temperature that you set the valve for. However, you would still be using the shower valve to mix cold water with the tempered hot water in order to adjust the temperature to the users liking. If there is a pressure drop on the cold system, the water out of the shower valve would still fluctuate hotter, but not hotter then the setting of the thermostatic mixing valve.

Comment: With those valves, is there any mixing done under normal conditions? Effectively lowering the maximum temperature but allowing a buffer in case hot water pressure drops?

Comment: I have no experience with these valves, but I must assume that under the conditions of normal operation where the hot water is coming out of your heater at 140 F you would want to mix in enough cold to get say 105 to 110 F in the hot line going into your mixing valve. So under normal operation the mixing valve would be drawing cold water. In your two handle mixing valve this water at 110 F would be mixed with cold water at say 70 F to give a final output of 100 F or less.  If the Watts valve has check valves built in, I don't get why it would need a separate one, but if that is what Watts say.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the link to the Watts valve you are considering. The link states that some of these Watts valves are intended for installation only at the water heater or boiler and are not suitable for final tempering of water at a fixture. So one approach would be to locate some tempering at the water heater to take water at 140 F down to say 115 F in the hot water supply lines, then you would have a fixture or another tempering valve to insure that the shower could not deliver water over say 105 F.

You really need to check with plumbing code enforcement in your area and see what they think is best and what they will approve. Even if you would cobble something together that would work for you, it might not pass inspection when you get ready to sell this house. It's far better to do something which works for you *and* satisfies the code.

> A Word about American Society of Sanitary Engineering (ASSE) Standards 1016, 1017 and 1070:   ASSE 1016 covers the delivery of water at the individual fixtures that are adjusted and controlled by the user. Therefore, it addresses very precise and immediate temperature regulation requirements. This standard covers three types of valves: Pressure Balancing, Thermostatic and Combined Pressure Balancing/Thermostatic. Watts ASSE 1016 listed valves meet the thermostatic requirements of this standard.

Modern commercially available temperature and/or pressure balancing shower valves *are* designed to both work satisfactorily and to meet plumbing codes requirements.

Comment: It's likely that your current plumbing is in compliance by being grandfathered in, but if you modify it and do not bring it up to current code, then it will not be in compliance.